# Data types nvarchar and nvarchar are incompatible

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get the following error when I run the lag function

```
select emplid, date,
coalesce(emplid - lag(emplid) over (order by date), 0) as diff
from queue
and ref in ('A','B')
```

Error:

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 432 The data types nvarchar and
> nvarchar are incompatible in the subtract operator.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[queue](
    [emplid] [nvarchar](33) NOT NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NULL,
    [ref] [nvarchar](100) NULL
    )
```

Comment: If the goal is to perform math on these values then `NVARCHAR` is the wrong data type in the first place.  Correcting the table schema is probably your best long-term solution.

Comment: The error is pretty clear - you can't subtract strings. What would be the result of `'Banana' - 'potato'` ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Concatenate the strings perhaps, to create `'Banana-potato'` ? Subtracting two EmployeeIDs isn't very useful even for numeric fields

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to subtract the Emplid from the previous row from the current row. Subtract is not allowed for NVARCHAR.

You can fix this, if your data allows, by casting it to the type which is stored. For example below, I assumed it is an INT value.

```
select emplid, date,
coalesce(CAST(emplid AS INT) - CAST(lag(emplid) as INT) over (order by date), 0) as diff
from queue
and ref in ('A','B')
```